# Python Library File Path Organization

Tags: python, libraries, organization

What is the best way to organize python libraries so that they are "seen" by a compiler?

I am new to downloading custom libraries in python and I am confused about where to save the libraries so that they can be read by my python compiler.

Often I have a new library downloaded onto my desktop, and I have my python compiler open, and I have stated the file path to the new library, but it still cannot be read.

How does a competent coder organize custom libraries?  Looking for advice and anecdotes.

*** Edit: I agree that this is a "simplistic question".  Also I would argue that the available documentation and tutorials geared around basic file and library organization in python (particularity around open-source libraries) is severely lacking for self-taught programmers.  ***

Comment: Are you using windows?

Comment: Yes.  I am using windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Programs and other executable files can be in many directories, so operating systems provide a search path that lists the directories that the OS searches for executables.
- The path is stored in an environment variable, which is a named string maintained by the operating system. This variable contains information available to the command shell and other programs.
- The path variable is named as PATH in Unix or Path in Windows (Unix is case sensitive; Windows is not).
- So in brief, you need to add python to path variable so that os can load it easily.
- Refer [add python to path](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html)
- After adding python to Path you need to install libraries in a specific location so that compiler can load them easily.
- From [doc](https://docs.python.org/3.3/using/windows.html),Python usually stores its library (and thereby your site-packages folder) in the installation directory. So, if you had installed Python to C:\Python\, the default library would reside in C:\Python\Lib\ and third-party modules should be stored in C:\Python\Lib\site-packages.
- You can install libraries manually and organise them as you wish. But there is a lot of overhead when we do it manually. Python has thousands of libraries. Installing and organizing them manually is really a headache. So you can use any package managers which will reduce your work considerably.
- There are many package managers in Python. For example pip, easy_install etc.

I suggest you to use **pip** - package management system for Python. It is very easy to use and you don't need to worry about the installed locations. 
 pip is already installed if you are using Python 2 >=2.7.9 or Python 3 >=3.4 downloaded from python.org. If it is not installed then install it by refering [install pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/). 
To install a package just type on terminal:

```
pip install packageName
```

The package will be downloaded to the location where Python can easily load it. 
Refer [pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/quickstart/) for further details.
Refer [Installing packages](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/) for knowing more about python package managers.

Comment: How does pip install packageName find where your package is installed without being directed to the package?  Does it search all files on your hard drive?  Also thank you, your answer so far has been helpful for me to conceptually understand python's file organization structure. @Mufeed

Comment: I updated the answer. I hope I cleared your doubts now.

Comment: Thanks! This was very helpful.